# Creating persistent netcat link

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssh-tunneling, netcat, autossh

I have a remote raspberrypi that uses autossh to connect to my local machine (with reverse tunnel -R). This should feed a dump1090 instance on my local machine. I'm using

```
/bin/nc localhost 40005 | /bin/nc localhost 30104
```

and it works great until the connection is good but when the link breaks the new connection isn't established. How can I make the netcat link persistent? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Kind of a hacky option, but you could just wrap your `nc` command(s) in a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    # your netcat command(s) here
done;
```

This'll keep re-launching the netcat stuff until you kill the script.

Comment: You might want a `sleep 1` in the loop too, to stop the loop running away on failure.

Comment: The main problem with this is that the netcat instance isn't killed when the link breaks, it just hangs.

Answer (score 2):

It was solved with socat utility. Thanks to all!

`/usr/bin/socat -u TCP:localhost:40005 TCP:localhost:30104`